# Microsoft Access: Multiple Records with Same ID need to exclude based off certain criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to filter out this data based on some criteria.

1. If the ID has more than 1 Focus, then I only want to keep the newest LastUpdatedDate record.
2. If the ID has 2 records with the same focus and same domain, keep the newest LastUpdatedDate record.
3. If the ID has 2 records with the same Focus, but different domains, and the stage is 3 or greater, then keep both records

Here is the sample data:

```
ID  LastUpdatedbyID Focus   Domain  Stage   LastUpdateDate  LastEndorsedDate
1   1       AT  APT 2   3/24/15 10:46 AM    3/24/15 10:46 AM
1   1       ES  ASS 2   3/27/15 10:23 AM    3/27/15 10:23 AM
1   1       ITC A   2   3/24/15 6:57 AM     3/24/15 6:57 AM
2   2       BP  Fin 2   4/10/15 8:48 AM     4/10/15 8:48 AM
2   2       BP  Fin 3   4/10/15 10:46 AM    4/10/15 12:00 AM
3   3       ES  CS  3   3/16/15 1:56 PM     3/16/15 12:00 AM
3   3       ES  PM  3   3/16/15 1:56 PM     3/16/15 12:00 AM
3   3       ES  PM  1   3/15/15 1:56 PM     3/15/15 2:00 PM
```

Here is the result:

```
ID  LastUpdatedbyID Focus   Domain  Stage   LastUpdateDate      LastEndorsedDate
1   1       ES  ASS 2   3/27/15 10:23 AM    3/27/15 10:23 AM
2   2       BP  Fin 3   4/10/15 10:46 AM    4/10/15 12:00 AM
3   3       ES  CS  3   3/16/15 1:56 PM     3/16/15 12:00 AM
3   3       ES  PM  3   3/16/15 1:56 PM     3/16/15 12:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example the source table is called `t` so change to its real name.

This query should give you the result you want. It's basically three different queries (one for each condition) combined using the union operator together. I don't imagine it performs that well and it can probably be improved, but with your sample data it did return the correct result when I tested it using Access 2010:

```
select t.* from t inner join (
    select id, max(LastUpdateDate) as aLastUpdateDate 
    from t 
    where id not in (select id from t group by id,focus, Domain having count(*) > 1) 
     and id not in (select id from t where stage >= 3 group by id,focus  having count(domain) > 1) 
    group by id having count(focus) > 1
) a on a.ID = t.id and a.aLastUpdateDate = t.LastUpdateDate

union all

select t.* from t inner join (
    select id, focus, Domain, max(LastUpdateDate) as bLastUpdateDate 
    from t 
    group by id,focus, Domain 
    having count(*) > 1
) b on b.ID=t.ID and b.Focus = t.Focus and b.Domain=t.Domain and b.bLastUpdateDate = t.LastUpdateDate

union all

select t.* from t inner join (
    select id, focus, stage
    from t 
    where stage >= 3 
    group by id,focus, stage
    having count(domain) > 1
) c on c.ID=t.ID and c.Focus = t.Focus and c.stage = t.stage
```

Comment: Your first 2 select statements functioned correctly, however the third select statement returned a row in my actual dataset that I wasn't expecting. I edited my original question and added the last row in my sample data. For some reason, it returned that row in my dataset. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @Kmart6700 I think I made a mistake. The last query should  probably include the stage too. I'll update the answer. Please give it a try now.